# The best method for training a neural network?

Tags: opencv, neural-network

I am trying to implement an OCR application that reads arabic numbers using Neural Network by openCV.

My Question is What give me the best performance and speed ?

1. entering the numbers to the NN in RGB form
2. entering the numbers to the NN in Grayscale form
3. entering the numbers to the NN in Binarized form

Comment: I've had pretty great success implementing this by using grayscale digits since they provide much less features that may not contribute as much, when compared to the RGB form.

Comment: What were the results when you tried to implement it using RGB or Binarized form ?

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it, color information is completely irrelevant to recognizing numbers. It might also be irrelevant for speed since it's more preprocessing than the NN (depending on your setup). Performance-wise there shouldn't be a big difference between grayscale and binary if you've implemented a proper model. But if you're curious, you can test it quite easily by just binarizing your training data and comparing the results. It may depend on the data at hand (e.g. any existing noise that gets amplified by naive binarization).